# AngularJS to redraw list of divs using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to redraw a list of divs after a user selects a different package but I couldn't find a way to have AngularJS redraw the divs after a package is selected.  Here is my sample codes: http://jsfiddle.net/bolto/a8Lmse80/13/

Or codes below:
Html

```
<div ng-controller="CarPackageCtrl" ng-mouseover="showPackageSelect()" ng-mouseleave="hidePackageSelect()">
    <div>{{car.name}}</div>
    <div ng-if="car.selected_package.one != undefined">{{car.selected_package.one}}</div>
    <div ng-if="car.selected_package.two != undefined">{{car.selected_package.two}}</div>
    <div ng-if="car.selected_package.three != undefined">{{car.selected_package.three}}</div>
    <div ng-if="car.selected_package.four != undefined">{{car.selected_package.four}}</div>
    <div ng-if="car.selected_package.five != undefined">{{car.selected_package.five}}</div>
    <div ng-if="car.isShowPackageSelect" class="dropdown pull-right">
        <div ng-repeat="i in [] | range:car.packages.length">
            <div class="radio_div_edit">
                <input class="radio" type="radio" name="group" ng-value="i" ng-model="selected" ng-click="setPackage(car.packages[i]);" />{{car.packages[i].name}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.filter('range', function () {
    return function (input, total) {
        total = parseInt(total);
        for (var i = 0; i < total; i++)
        input.push(i);
        return input;
    };
});

app.controller('CarPackageCtrl', ['$scope',

function ($scope) {
    $scope.car = new Object();
    $scope.car.name = "Keslar";
    $scope.car.isShowPackageSelect = true; // should init to false but having trouble with getting ng-mouseover to work, so setting it to false for now
    var package = new Object();
    package.name = "Basic";
    package.one = "stereo";
    package.two = "sunroof";
    package.five = "spoiler";
    $scope.car.packages = [];
    $scope.car.packages.push(package);

    var package2 = new Object();
    package2.name = "Intermediate";
    package2.two = "sunroof";
    package2.three = "GPS";
    package2.four = "rear video";
    package2.five = "spoiler";
    $scope.car.packages.push(package2);

    var package3 = new Object();
    package3.name = "Power";
    package3.one = "stereo";
    package3.two = "sunroof";
    package3.three = "GPS";
    package3.four = "rear video";
    package3.five = "spoiler";
    $scope.car.packages.push(package3);

    $scope.car.selected_package = $scope.car.packages[0];
    $scope.showPackageSelect = function showPackageSelect($scope) {
        $scope.car.isShowPackageSelect = true;
    }
    $scope.hidePackageSelect = function hidePackageSelect($scope) {
        $scope.car.isShowPackageSelect = false;
    }
    $scope.setPackage = function setPackage($scope, package) {
        $scope.car.selected_package = package;
    }
}]);
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'redraw' ?

Comment: @ThomasP1988, each car.packages[i] has a different number of items, so if car.selected_package has more/less items than previous one, the number of items (thus divs) should be redrawn, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you right, you meant something like this

```
$scope.setPackage = function(pack){
    $scope.car.selected_package = pack;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a8Lmse80/15/

Comment: Wow, yes, exactly how I wanted it.  I did it with     $scope.setPackage = function setPackage($scope, package) {
        $scope.car.selected_package = package;
    }, can you tell me why when I have $scope include, it does not work?  I thought $scope is always used if we are setting something from the parent controller.